# Material-UI import order changes styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm learning MUI and I had difficulties debugging a CSS issue.
Basically, my styling would break after exporting a  into its own component.
After a ton of trial and error, I found that my imports were the culprit...

I first had this:

```js
import {
Avatar,
CardContent,
CardHeader,
CssBaseline,
IconButton,
Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
```

This didn't work, but changing the  import to this fixed it:

```js
import {
Card,
Avatar,
CardContent,
CardHeader,
CssBaseline,
IconButton,
Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
```

Could someone help me understand why this happens, and is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a `named import` in combination with a `default import` for the same library.

A `named import` is the import with bracket:

```
import {
Avatar,
CardContent,
CardHeader,
CssBaseline,
IconButton,
Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
```

A `default import` is the import without bracket:

```
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
```

So you have to decide. If you want to use a `named import` you should use your current solution:

```
import {
Card,
Avatar,
CardContent,
CardHeader,
CssBaseline,
IconButton,
Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
```

If you want to use a `default import` you should write:

```
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
...
```

Comment: oh wow, it's that simple, somehow I've been working with react for a couple of months but never learned this.. thanks!